# Targeting the div if it has a class then hiding the divs with similar classes - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So the below code is hiding all the elements with class `abc` but I want to hide only the div with class `xyz`. Using `this` is obviously not gonna work but it requires the similar functionality as `this` keyword.

HTML Code

```
<body>
   <button id="xyz">xyz</button>
   <button id="mno">mno</button>
   <button id="cde">cde</button>
   <div class='abc xyz'></div>
   <div class='abc mno'></div>
   <div class='abc xyz'></div>
   <div class='abc cde'></div>
   <div class='abc xyz'></div>
   <div class='abc mno'></div>
   <div class='abc xyz'></div>
</body>
```

JQuery Code

```
$('#xyz').on('click',function(){
   if($('.abc').hasClass('xyz')){
        $('.abc').hide();
   }
   else {
        $('.abc').show();
   }
});
$('#mno').on('click',function(){
   if($('.abc').hasClass('mno')){
        $('.abc').hide();
   }
   else {
        $('.abc').show();
   }
});
```

When I click on button `xyz` it hide all the div's which doesn't have the class `.xyz` and when I click on button `mno` it will hide all the other div's but the div's with class `.mno` will show up!

Comment: `$(".abc.xyz")`

Comment: Use $(".abc.xyz").hide()

Comment: When you click on `.abc.mno` for example, do you want the other hidden `.xyz` to be shown ?

Comment: `$(".abc.xyz").hide();$(".abc:not(.xyz)").show();`

Comment: yes @ZakariaAcharki, like filtering the divs with class `.xyz` to be shown and others will be hidden and vice versa

Answer (score 2):

Why not just create a specific query for that class?

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
   $('.abc.xyz').hide();
});
```

Comment: I've edited the code to be more specific of the requirements!

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to understand what you need,

If you want to show all `.abc` but hide all `.abc.xyz`, do in this way:

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
   $('.abc').show();
   $('.abc.xyz').hide();
});
```

If you want to show/hide only the element that was clicked on, do this:

```
$('button').on('click',function(event) {
   var element = $(event.target);
   if(element.hasClass('xyz')){
       element.hide();
   } else {
       element.show();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `this` keyword with common class like the snippet belw shows.

Hope this helps.

```js
$('.toggle-div').on('click', function() {
  $('.abc').hide();
  
  $('.abc.' + $(this).attr('id') ).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class='toggle-div' id="xyz">xyz</button>
<button class='toggle-div' id="mno">mno</button>
<button class='toggle-div' id="cde">cde</button>

<br>

<div class='abc xyz'>xyz</div>
<div class='abc mno'>mno</div>
<div class='abc xyz'>xyz</div>
<div class='abc cde'>cde</div>
<div class='abc xyz'>xyz</div>
<div class='abc mno'>mno</div>
<div class='abc xyz'>xyz</div>
```